# Unable to use space or 'n' key in <input /> element

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

OK, this is driving me absolutely crazy, and I can't for the life of me figure out why this odd behaviour is occuring.

With the following HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="input_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Your Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_name" name="name" value="">
     </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I try to type into the `<input />` element, I'm unable to use either the <kbd>[space]</kbd> or <kbd>N</kbd>.

I am using Bootstrap, but have never encountered this problem before. The issue exists in Google Chrome (35.0.1916.153), Firefox (30.0) and Safari all on a Mac. The problem also exists on Windows in Google Chrome (34.0.1847.131 m).

The live URL for the page can be seen here > [**http://med-dept.com/contact-us/**](http://med-dept.com/contact-us/)

Any assistance really would be appreciated, as this is very annoying....

Comment: It is working perfectly fine in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/grzT5/. Guess you need to provide some more code, you might be having some validation set

Comment: Have you got some validation code on this?

Comment: "_We are currently in the process of redesigning the MRC website and moving it to another, faster server. This means that the site will be inaccessible from 00:00 (BST) Tuesday (1 July 2014) for a period of approximately 24 hours_" ...?

Comment: @DavidG no. Please check the live link.

Comment: @davidkonrad Sorry - forgot about that. Try now?

Comment: It seems to be a problem somewhere in JavaScript, because with Firefox + NoScript I can type whatever I want (N and [space] is working)

Comment: @BenM It's definitely some sort of Javascript getting in the way, turning it off makes it work.

Comment: Still no luck. Perhaps because I'm outside UK?

Comment: P doesn't work either :-)

Comment: Hmm, there is no JS that I've added which would cause this strange behaviour.

Comment: I found it! It's the lightbox.js addon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lightbox.js has this code which is preventing your keypresses:

```
// Register our shortcuts:
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode)
    {
        case 27: // esc
            e.preventDefault();
            hideLightbox();
            break;

        case 39: // right arrow
        case 40: // down arrow
        case 78: // N
        case 32: // space
            e.preventDefault();
            nextImage();
            break;

        case 37: // left arrow
        case 38: // up arrove
        case 80: // P
            e.preventDefault();
            prevImage();
            break;
    }

});
```

Comment: I had a feeling it was js, space, n and p are too specific to be anything else. Glad to help!